# Converting a proprietary raw image format to Adobe DNG

Tags: image, dng

I have a proprietary raw camera image format taken from a Aptina camera. It's raw file format is 16bit per color channel, 'GRBG' mode with file extension is *.raw. No headers nothing, just plan raw bayer samples. I want to convert this format to DNG, as none of the raw image decoders (dcraw,gimp,...) seem to support it.

1] Is there any tool/converter which can handle Aptina camera sensor raw bayer format, and allow me to convert it to DNG format?

2] If not, I want to write a small C code to convert it myself. Where can I find the detail specification about DNG format, its structure etc. Any document explaining all this DNG format?

Answer (score 1):

The specification for DNG lies at http://www.adobe.com/products/dng/pdfs/dng_spec_1_3_0_0.pdf 
There are several versions though managed as [explained](http://www.barrypearson.co.uk/articles/dng/specification.htm#versions). Check out the Adobe DNG Converter, it might help.

You could contact [Aptina](http://www.aptina.com/how_to_buy/sales_support.jsp) if you are motivated ;)
There is an FOSS library that handles RAW at http://www.libraw.org/
but it seems to require headers to be able to work, as it is based on dcraw.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for C code, there is a basic converter for raw 16-bit Bayer images into DNG [here](http://openendedgroup.com/field/GigECamerasAndField). It only supplies enough DNG information to get it to load but that should be fine for feeding it into image processing applications.